# How can I do checking before task in Activiti (6.0.0) (BPMN 2.0)?

Tags: activiti, bpmn

[Checking before task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcRro.jpg)
I am trying realised checking before task 3 but if I put it before task 3 it is checking executed immediately after second task, but I am need so it executed before starting of task 3. How can I do it?
[Variant 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjLFm.jpg)  If I put checking near task 3 so (Variant 2), it is executed after  completing task 3 and I can't change status task 3

I tried above solution but it doesn't work hoew I expected